# Why can't you stringify a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The line `JSON.stringify( $("p") );` causes an error:

```
InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('button') does not support selection.
```

<sup>(I'm using Google Chrome 34)</sup>

Why?

How else should I make `$("p")` more portable so I can store it or pass it in a message?

Comment: why do you want to stringify an object? What is the purpose? You should be storing watever you need in a json object and stringify that instead right?

Comment: Why oh why would you want to store a jQuery selection set of DOM elements or make it portable in the first place? What is in those `p`s?

Comment: What is the actual context for the question? It is hard to see how passing the results of a jQuery selector would ever need to be passed in a message. Unless you just need the HTML, in which case wouldn't `$('p').html()` be sufficient?

Comment: why don't you just send the text content and handle the text content, rather than having to send the whole p object?

Comment: The context is a chrome extension--communicating between a content script and a background script. I suppose stringification isn't truly necessary...it's just that being able to stringify a jQuery object would make implementation really straightforward.

Comment: Why not just pass the selector?

Comment: @Petah Hm. Probably should have said this in the question, but it's not actually a selector, it's a jQuery( DOMelement ). Also, I need the .css() and .text(). You have a point though....maybe I can stringify certain components and reconstruct the jQuery object from a stringified DOMelement?

Comment: @jonS90 What is requirement ? Please clarify. If possible, please post `html`, `css`, `js` . Thanks

Comment: @jonS90 how about using the ID of the element? (or setting a UID if there is none)

Comment: @Petah I can't count on an ID....what is this UID you speak of?

Comment: @jonS90 `if (!$('foo').attr('id')) { $('foo').attr('id', 'uid-' + Math.random()); }`

Comment: @Petah Oh, I see...that might just do it. Much thanks!

Answer (score 9):

There's a ton of state (attributes, event handlers, the code related to those, internal state, ...) involved in an HTML element. It just doesn't make sense to serialize all of that into JSON.

If you want to get *some kind of representation* of the element in JSON, you could for instance use `.html()` to get a HTML string representing the element. Or come up with a format that encodes, for instance, tag names, attributes and text only. You could have to implement that by hand though (or find a library - "html to json" could be a good keyword)

Comment: If he needs the `p` tag it may be better to call `outerHMTL` on it to capture the `p` tag itself.

Comment: @izuriel: Yes, that would also work for a single element. I got the feeling that he might actually have multiple though, and in that case adding them to a dummy element and using `html()` seems like the easiest way to get a HTML string out of them.

Comment: The HTML alone won't allow me to reconstruct the jQuery object. I think the representation should have a unique ID or Class (from which I can reconstruct the jQuery object), and additionally any components I will need, such as `.html()` and `.css()` stuff. 
This has been a huge help!