# What is Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey doing to my jQuery object when I use GM_setValue?

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm trying to select DOM elements into a Tampermonkey variable using `GM_setValue`, for later injection on different pages.

I've created an example where I can do this in normal jQuery using `.clone()`, but when I set it as a value in Tampermonkey, it changes the value of the saved variable.

Here's an HTML page to test the script on:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<style>
    div {
      border: solid 1px black;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- these buttons controlled by grease monkey-->
    <div>
         GreaseMonkey <button id="copy"> save</button>
        <button id="paste"> paste </button>
    </div>
    <div>
         Local <button id="copyLocal"> save</button>
        <button id="pasteLocal"> paste </button>
    </div>
    <div id="bar"> hello world </div>
    <script>
        var ele;
         $("#copyLocal").click(function() {
            console.log("copy");
           ele =  $("#bar").clone();
           console.log(ele);
        });
        $("#pasteLocal").click(function(){
            console.log("paste");
            console.log(ele);
           $("body").append(ele);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the corresponding Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @require https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js
// @match        file:///C:/david/sandbox/jquery/index.html
// @grant        GM_setValue
// @grant GM_getValue
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#copy").click(function() {
        console.log("copy");

           var ele = $("#bar").clone();
           console.log(ele);
       GM_setValue("ele", ele); 
    });

    $("#paste").click(function(){
        console.log("paste");

        var ele = GM_getValue("ele");
        console.log(ele);
       $("body").append(ele);
    });

       console.log("ready");
    });
})();
```

Here's the console output:

[image]

As you can see - Tampermonkey (I also tried this with Greasemonkey) appears to be stripping the jQuery out of the jQuery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GM_setValue()` [only works on: strings, (some) integers and booleans](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue).

In your code, `ele` is an *object*.
Now for *simple* objects, you can GM_setValue them by first JSON encoding them. BUT your object is a complex jQuery object and these cannot be JSON encoded. (Once upon a time [the attempt would throw a JS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073216/why-cant-you-stringify-a-jquery-object). Nowadays, `JSON.stringify` will just omit all the problematic properties, leaving you without the stuff you need the  most.)

The question shows **you are apparently just cloning HTML. If that's true, you don't need to try and store a jQuery object.  Just store the HTML.**

Something like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    New Userscript
// @require https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js
// @match   file:///C:/david/sandbox/jquery/index.html
// @grant   GM_setValue
// @grant   GM_getValue
// ==/UserScript==

$("#copy").click (function () {
    console.log ("copy");

    var ele = $("#bar").html ();
    console.log (ele);
    GM_setValue ("ele", ele);
} );

$("#paste").click (function () {
    console.log ("paste");

    var ele = GM_getValue ("ele");
    console.log (ele);
    $("body").append (ele);
} );

console.log ("ready");
```

PS: The wrapping cruft I omitted is stuff that you almost never need in a GM/TM script.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work for what I'm actually trying to do - which is to bind data to the my DOM elements, and save the state of them. I'm going to look at using cookies instead.

Comment: You can still bind data. Just don't use jQuery's `.data()`. Use data attributes; that way the data is stored in the HTML and thus `GM_setValue`.  You may have to JSON encode your data first.  ... Finally, don't use cookies.  These get sent to the server and are flaky as get-out (for reasons).  If you go that route, use `localStorage` instead.