# Store Dexie database in Tampermonkey storage

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, dexie

I'm using a TamperMonkey script in FireFox, with the following libraries: jQuery 2.1.4, Dexie.js, json2html 1.2.0, and Bootstrap 3.4.0. I'm trying to persist a Dexie object (for a Dexie database) into TamperMonkey's local storage with `GM.setValue('unique-dexie-db-name', dexieDBvariable);` However when I go to retrieve this value (*ex. I store this on google.com, and retrieve this on yahoo.com*) with `var dexieDB = GM.getValue('unique-dexie-db-name');` My returned object value is not a Dexie database object, but rather something else I can't use as a database.

My question: I'm unsure, but I think when storing this Dexie Database into TamperMonkey, it gets stored as a string, and, I should try to somehow stringify the object fully in order to be able to reproduce and re-create it when I need it in the `GM.getValue()` call. How do I store this Javascript object as a string in order to be able to retrieve the value again as a whole later?

Comment: This is probably a dupe q, but you need to `JSON.stringify()` what you store with `setValue`. Then `JSON.parse()` what you retrieve with `getValue`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I noticed that in the [duplicate question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40167822/what-is-greasemonkey-tampermonkey-doing-to-my-jquery-object-when-i-use-gm-setval) that complex objects are not able to be stringify'd or parsed as they loose fine detailed properties. Do you by chance know if that has been changed since 2016 (year the question was asked) or, perhaps I should explore alternative routes - like loading and storing the entire DB before the GM.setValue, then reloading it when calling GM.getValue - so that the data entries are preserved?

Comment: Try storing your data.  If it's not complex DOM, nor recursive, it should work.

Comment: I created a new Dexie object, opened it, then added an entry to it. My results were not promising, as errors occurred after storing the Dexie object with JSON.stringify() then trying to load a new Dexie object and extracting with JSON.parse(). I was hopeful for the simple approch, but perhaps there is a Dexie method specific to this issue? or, perhaps I should try extracting all the entries as json from the DB then saving the raw json data to TamperMonkey with GM.setValue, and load all the raw data back when needing to access the Dexie DB with GM.getValue()?

Comment: Can't say without more specifics.  If you can link to a specific public page and/or create a [mre], then open a new question. Otherwise it's too broad.

Comment: Here's my example script in a gist - https://gist.github.com/n-bell/b375c80b638d3a59a250e903afb4a36b.js -- should I create a new question based on my original w/ the additional details of the gist?

Comment: Perhaps, but that example does not JSON parse `GM.getValue(tmObj)` in at least 1 instance where it needs to.

Comment: Oh shoot, ok, I'll retry my debug routine as I don't think I understood right off the back where that is. I know 'tmDBObj' is a promise and shouldn't need a parse. I also tried switching `let openDBFromFile = JSON.parse(data);` in the only else case on the snippet - thought this might have been where I needed it as the function returned by the initial 'tmDBObj' promise has `data` in the return function - but this gave me an error when trying to query it - `TypeError: openDBFromFile.logHistory.where is not a function` - any hints or tips?

Comment: Open a new question here or on codereview.

Comment: cheers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57938009/reopen-dexie-database-with-tampermonkey