# Reopen Dexie Database with Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, dexie

As per my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57929417/6393165), I was referred to create a new post.
As seen in the comments, there is a trail of progression for the issue, I'll rephrase here in this post:

I'm using a TamperMonkey script in FireFox.

I'm trying to persist a [Dexie](https://dexie.org/) object/database into TamperMonkey's local storage with `GM.setValue('unique-dexie-db-name', dexieDBvariable);`

However when I go to retrieve this value (ex. I store this on google.com, and retrieve this on yahoo.com) with `var dexieDB = GM.getValue('unique-dexie-db-name');` My returned object value is not a Dexie database object, but rather something else I can't use as a database.

My question: I'm unsure, but I think when storing this Dexie Database into TamperMonkey, it gets stored as a string, and, I should try to somehow `JSON.stringify()` the object fully in order to be able to reproduce and re-create it when I need it in the `GM.getValue()` call. How do I store this Javascript object as a string in order to be able to retrieve the value again as a whole later?

This is my working example code;

https://gist.github.com/n-bell/b375c80b638d3a59a250e903afb4a36b.js

https://gist.github.com/n-bell/b375c80b638d3a59a250e903afb4a36b

(second link looks better formatted in browser)

And, as stated before, I've tried playing around with `JSON.parse()` / `JSON.stringify()` but I'm not sure this is the path to go down.

Comment: IndexedDb is domain specific. You can't access data stored while on domainA from domainB. Same rules apply to using localStorage

Comment: @charlietfl so since Dexie uses indexedDB, that means internally, it wouldn't be feasible in the first place (due to the way that IndexedDB stores the database as domain specific) to try to cross site store a database in GM's storage?

Comment: Right because the only window your userscript has access to is the current one

Comment: Actually, if you fix the code to use `GM.getValue` correctly, you will then get an error like `"openDBFromFile.logHistory.where is not a function"`.  This is because the Dexie object is not fully serializable, and things like the prototype functions are not in the JSON.  It might be possible to extract the data and use it to seed a new Dixie instance, maybe. But you're not paying me enough to attempt it. ;)   Also, this is yet another case where trying to make code work on GM4 leads to needless hassle for no gain and breaks on all other engines but Tampermonkey. (Use `GM_getValue`.)

Comment: Thanks for the messages. I think I found my answer - no answer. I don't see a solution in GM/Tampermonkey being the resolve in my case given the thorough explanations. Cheers